# Discriminações "de qualquer natureza" ou "de quaisquer naturezas"?

Tags: número-gramatical

Recentemente, em seu discurso de posse como presidente do Senado Federal, o senador R.P. declarou:

> A partir desse momento não existem mais divisões, somente assim poderemos caminhar em busca do que realmente precisamos neste momento, criar uma sociedade justa e livre, desprovida de preconceitos e **discriminações de quaisquer naturezas**. [link](https://www12.senado.leg.br/radio/1/noticia/2021/02/01/novo-presidente-do-senado-defende-harmonia-entres-os-poderes)

Eu então pergunto: por que não dizer "de qualquer natureza"?  Por que usar o plural?  Embora não me pareça ferir a gramática, é correto esse uso?